# Write Raspberry Pi program, without a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

Im soon gonna buy a Raspberry Pi, but I dont want to wait until I get it to start writing my program.

- My PI is gonna be connected to the TV, and have a GUI.
- Im gonna write my program in Python

Can I just start writing a GUI application on my computer, and just push it over, or is is something that I need to think about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can setup a virtual machine with linux on it. This way you can test the compatibility of your code. If it runs on linux, it will most surely will run on the raspberry (which also runs linux).

In the case of Python, it should even run fine when tested on windows, unless you use OS specific features.

Comment: Cool. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem, enjoy the pi! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well when you want program in python is simple on windows but you have to choose version (raspberry pi has both) [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) In this gui you can program what you want and after raspi comes only transfer program :) have good fun :)